# custom boundary of image in swift

Tags: ios, swift, boundary

I want to convert the boundary of this image from rectangle to hexagonal. 
I know how to implement custom boundary for a button.But how to implement it for a image?

Upon tapping on corner of a one image the adjacent image gets tapped.

Here is the code snippet for tap recognizer which detects the boundary of image and take some action accordingly.

```
import UIKit
class Game: UIViewController {
    var flag:Bool! = false
@IBOutlet var fields: [SIXImageView]!
 var currentPlayer:String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 setupField ()

}

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func fieldTapped (recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    let tappedField  = recognizer.view as SIXImageView
    tappedField.setPlayer(currentPlayer)

    let messageDict = ["field":tappedField.tag, 
    "player":currentPlayer]}


 func setupField () {
     currentPlayer = "x"
    for index in 0 ... fields.count - 1{
        let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "fieldTapped:")
        gestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        fields[index].addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
        checkResults()
    }


}
```

[image: Image having square boundary]

```
Image having square boundary
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to convert an `UIImageView` from rectagular shape to hexagonal shape :

```
var rect = image.frame
var hexagonMask = CAShapeLayer()
var hexagonBorder = CAShapeLayer()
hexagonBorder.frame = image.layer.bounds

var hexagonPath = UIBezierPath()
var sideWidth : CGFloat = 2 * ( 0.5 * rect.size.width / 2 )
var lcolumn = ( rect.size.width - sideWidth ) / 2

var rcolumn : CGFloat = rect.size.width - lcolumn;
var height : CGFloat = 0.966025 * rect.size.height;
var y : CGFloat = (rect.size.height - height) / 2;
var by : CGFloat = rect.size.height - y;
var midy : CGFloat = rect.size.height / 2;
var rightmost : CGFloat = rect.size.width;


hexagonPath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(lcolumn, y))
hexagonPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(rcolumn, y))
hexagonPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(rightmost, midy))
hexagonPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(rcolumn, by))
hexagonPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(lcolumn, by))
hexagonPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(0, midy))
hexagonPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(lcolumn, y))

hexagonMask.path = hexagonPath.CGPath
hexagonBorder.path = hexagonPath.CGPath
hexagonBorder.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
hexagonBorder.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
hexagonBorder.lineWidth = 5

image.layer.mask = hexagonMask
image.layer.cornerRadius = 10
image.layer.masksToBounds = true
image.layer.addSublayer(hexagonBorder)
```

You can play with the values for `height` , `width`, etc.
I hope this help you.

Comment: @lazyrabbit Any problem with the answer? It round the corners to a hexagon isn't?